# Any idea what this part is?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

I have bought a mixed bag, with not many booklets. This LEGO part has no part number, I'm trying to find it's set number.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

This should be this part [Windscreen 8 x 6 x 2 Curved](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=x224pb012&idColor=86#T=C&C=86) 
which appeared only in one set wit those stickers: [Separatist Shuttle 8036](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8036-1#T=I)
[image]

Comment: The middle decal seems to be backward between this and the OP's piece...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman presumably it was applied incorrectly?